# Como migrar una BD Mysql a MongoDB para ser usada en Django Rest Framework

Tags: mysql, mongodb, djangorestframework, migration

Necesito los datos que están en una BD MySQL para un nuevo proyecto Django Rest Framework donde quiero usar MongoDB para tener campos dinámicos en los modelos.
He estado buscando y hasta ahora lo mejor que me encontrado para lograrlo ha sido

1. Crear el Proyecto DRF y los modelos, ejecutar el migrate para que se cree el esquema de la BD
2. Migrar manualmente los datos de la BD MySQL a la base de datos MongoDB creada en el paso anterior

La Base de datos MySQL es bastante grande, por lo que me gustaría saber si esta es la mejor manera antes de intentar hacer todo eso manualmente.

Comment: Nunca ha sido trivial migrar una base de datos SQL a una noSQL, por lo cual cualquiera que sea el camino que escojas tendrá aristas muy particulares. Por otro lado, tu pregunta se basa totalmente en opiniones, lo cual es motivo de cierre. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Saludos

Comment: Creo que primero deberías revisar "el porqué" cambiar a mongo, depende de lo que tengas actualmente puede no ser una buena idea.